# Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am working on elastic search in spring boot rest API. I am trying to add distance based query. I am getting following exception while running:

`Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]`

Following is my code:

```
// Geo distance
        GeoDistanceSortBuilder distanceSortBuilder = new GeoDistanceSortBuilder("location", latitude, longitude);
        distanceSortBuilder.unit(DistanceUnit.MILES);
        distanceSortBuilder.order(SortOrder.ASC);

        DisMaxQueryBuilder searchByParameterQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.disMaxQuery();
        searchByParameterQueryBuilder.add(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(parameterType, "*" + searchParameter + "*"));

        System.out.println(parameterType + ": " + searchByParameterQueryBuilder);
        // System.out.println("");

        // Distance query
        QueryBuilder distanceQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder().must(QueryBuilders.geoDistanceQuery("location")
                .point(latitude, longitude).distance(distance, DistanceUnit.MILES)).must(searchByParameterQueryBuilder);

        // System.out.println("Distance query: " + distanceQuery);

        Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withFilter(distanceQuery).withSort(distanceSortBuilder)
                .build();

        System.out.println("Search query: " + searchQuery);

        SearchHits<Elastic_Business_Service_Model> serviceHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(searchQuery,
                Elastic_Business_Service_Model.class, IndexCoordinates.of(Business_Service_Index));
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: can you print your query in JSON format, also share your index mapping and settings?